# Arduino ATMega32u4 USB pinout

Tags: arduino, usb, dc, atmega, 5v

Really quick question here - is it possible to use the GND/5V from the USB cable to power the Arduino through the USB connector *but* use the RX/TX pins to a motherboard's USB pin headers (D+/D-)?

```
The D+ = TX
The D- = RX
```

Then connect the common grounds (5V, GND and motherboard GND together).

So:

```
5V (psu) ---------> Arduino USB \$V_{cc}\$ connector
GND (psu) --------> Arduino USB GND connector
TX (Arduino pin) -> motherboard USB header D+
RX (Arduino pin) -> motherboard USB header D- 
GND (Arduino pin -> motherboard USB header GND
```

Will the GND pin on the Arduino be considered "combined" since the PSU GND is connected via the USB connector (grounding both USB GND and motherboard GND)?

The Arduino I am using is this:

[image: Freaduino Micro V1.2]

Comment: Well, as of this writing it has been 12 hours sisnce you asked this question and I am the first comment.  I think that supports what I am about to say which is: What are you talking about? What motherboard where? My suggestion would be that you will need to provide some more information to get a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to power the Arduino with a different power supply than the motherboard. This is common for self-powered devices and the device's datasheet will have a section with the recommended schematic for that configuration. The GND will be tied together and IIRC the +5V is used to detect the connection.

You can consult the datasheet and the board's schematic to see whether you can reproduce the datasheet's schematic for self-powered devices with a hacked USB cable.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about http://elecfreaks.com/store/download/Freaduino%20microV1.2.pdf board you can power from USB connector and use serial RX/TX 32u2' 5V serial pins. D+/- are high frequency USB data wires dedicated to USB only. You can make ugly hack, unsolder R3&R10 and wire D+/- to RX/TX. But it's really really awfull reusing USB connector as 5V serial.